# How can I parallelize the inner loops with openMP?

Tags: c++, openmp, xeon-phi

Perhaps the solution to my problem is very obvious. I want to accelerate the following code using openMP (into Intel Xeon Phi), but I can't.

```
int c=0, d=0, e=0, i;
#pragma opm parallel for private(c, d, e)
for(i=0; i < columns; i++)
{
  if((left_side[rule*columns + i] > 0) || (right_side[rule*columns + i] > 0))
  {
    for(c=0; c < rows; c++)
    {
      if(left_side[i + c * columns] > 0)
      {
        if(flag[c] == 0)
        {
          r_prob[c] = c_vect[c];
          flag[c] = 1;
          for(d=0; d < columns; d++)
          {
            switch(left_side[c * columns + d])
            {
              case 0:
                break;
              case 1:
                r_prob[c] *= M_in[d] * 1.0;
                break;
              case 2:
                r_prob[c] *= (M_in[d] * (M_in[d] - 1)) * .5;
                break;
              default:
                for(e=1; e <= left_side[c * columns + d]; e++)
                  r_prob[c] *= M_in[d] * 1.0 / (e * 1.0);
                break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
//where r_prob, M_in, left_side, right_side, c_vect and flag are array that are in input.
```

This code doesn't run correctly, the values in r_prob are wrong.
How I can parallelize this code?

Comment: Is there a specific reasons why `c`, `d`, `e` and most of all `i` are not declared inside the parallel loop?

Comment: I guess the reason is because it is programming in pure C language. In C ++ you can declare variables within each FOR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code has an error because the first FOR creating multiple threads, and these simultaneously written to the array r_prob, flag. The solution could be:

```
int c=0, d=0, e=0, i;
#pragma opm parallel for private(c, d, e)
 for(i=0; i < columns; i++)
 {

 if((left_side[rule*columns + i] > 0) || (right_side[rule*columns + i] > 0))
 {
  for(c=0; c < rows; c++)
  {
  if(left_side[i + c * columns] > 0)
  {
    if(flag[c] == 0)
    {
       #pragma omp critical //Only one thread at a time can enter 
      { 
      r_prob[c] = c_vect[c];
      flag[c] = 1;
      }

      for(d=0; d < columns; d++)
      {
        switch(left_side[c * columns + d])
        {
          case 0:
            break;
          case 1:
             #pragma omp critical //Only one thread at a time can enter 
             { 
            r_prob[c] *= M_in[d] * 1.0;
              }
            break;
          case 2:
             #pragma omp critical //Only one thread at a time can enter 
             { 
            r_prob[c] *= (M_in[d] * (M_in[d] - 1)) * .5;
             }
            break;
          default:
            for(e=1; e <= left_side[c * columns + d]; e++)
               #pragma omp critical //Only one thread at a time can enter 
               {
              r_prob[c] *= M_in[d] * 1.0 / (e * 1.0);
              }
            break;
           }
          }
       }
     }
   }
 }
}//where r_prob, M_in, left_side, right_side, c_vect and flag are array that are in input.
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that different threads write to and read from the same `r_prob[c]` variable. With this algorithm you can either parallelize the loop over `c` only. I.e. write:

```
for(int i=0; i < columns; i++)
{
  if((left_side[rule*columns + i] > 0) || (right_side[rule*columns + i]  > 0))
  {
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int c=0; c < rows; c++){
      //....
```

Or you can use the syntax:

```
#pragma omp critical
{
   r_prob[c] *= ...
}
```

syntax to only allow one thread at a time to access the array.

Which one is faster depends on the size of the arrays and number of threads.

As commented by Haatschii it's better to declare the variables inside the for loop.